# make login in ExpressJS whit AWS cognito user pool

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-cognito

i'm trying to make a login in Express with AWS Cognito. In my code, i have a tag "a" whit href contains a link for authorize API of AWS:

`GET https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=ad398u21ijw3s9w3939&                          redirect_uri=https://YOUR_APP/redirect_uri&state=STATE&scope=openid+profile+aws.cognito.signin.user.admin`

i get a url with "callback-uri + auhtcode", i take a code and i should send it a token API.
In my code i used a fetch:

```
async function getToken(auth_code){
    const response = await fetch("https://greenenergy.auth.eu-north-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token"
    ,{
        method:"POST",
        headers:{
            "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        },
        body:{
            grant_type: "authorization_code",
            client_id:"",
            client_secret:"",
            redirect_uri:"http://localhost:3001",
            code: auth_code

        }
    });
    
}
```

it's correct? do you have other options?

but it doesn't work, it doesn't send me the jwt token

with postman it comes back to me a token